# Why does c use abbreviations for everything?

Tags: c

For example, why does the language use `argv` instead of `argumentVector`, or `argVector` (or `argument_vector`, depending on your preference) or `malloc` instead of `allocateMemory` or `allocMem`? Is there a justification? It seems to me that the abbreviations selected are also fairly obtuse. This is especially evident in the case of `malloc`, where "m" is placed before "alloc", which is especially unintuitive. Is there a way to go about thinking about this that will make it clearer and more readily apparent, or is this just a barrier to entry that I'll need to memorize?

Also, I've only been able to find answers about why people who program in c abbreviate extensively. This is about abbreviation in c as a language, not abbreviation as a stylistic convention.

Comment: Historical reasons. Back in the 70s computers were very limited and so the first C compilers had a restriction of 8 characters for any identifier

Comment: **M**emory **Alloc**ator. And if my memory serves, some systems had limits on the length of symbol names.

Comment: You are perfectly free to define `int main(int argumentCount, char *argumentVector[])` if you wish, but I find names that are overly long are harder to read. The right balance is needed: the function `malloc` isn't confusing, to me, but if you want to quibble about the use of `int j` then I'm with you.

Comment: @UnholySheep: 8?  Nah, C89/C90 had a limit of 6 characters, case-insensitive, on external names.  See also [Why must the first 31 characters of an identifier be unique?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19905944/why-must-the-first-31-characters-of-an-identifier-be-unique)

Answer (score 3):

Historical note:

70's and early 80's era compilers allowed symbol names that were *greater* than 8 characters. Meaning that the compiler would parse them. But only the first 8 characters were stored into the symbol table and treated as significant/different when comparing symbol names.

So, you *could* have longer symbol names but the additional characters were ignored, so automatic variables (function scope) had to be unique in the first 8 characters:

```
int
main()
{
    int abcdefg0;  // unique
    int abcdefg1;  // unique

    int abcdefgh0;  // not unique
    int abcdefgh1;  // not unique

    int bcdefghiXXX;  // unique but truncated to [treated as] bcdefghi

    return 0;
}
```

The linker/loader allowed 8 character names. But, for a *global* (e.g.):

```
int foo;

int
bar()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler would change the names by adding a prefix of `_` [to distinguish C symbols from asm symbols]. So, we'd get `_foo` and `_bar` respectively in the `.o` file.

So, C global names had to be unique in the first 7 characters. Otherwise, `abcdefg0/abcdefg1` (in the source file and compiler symbol table) --> `_abcdefg0/_abcdefg1` (with compiler adding the prefix) --> `_abcdefg/_abcdefg` (in the `.o`)

(i.e.) A collision when linking.

Because of this, IIRC, most programmers kept even automatic/function scoped variables unique in the first 7 characters (even though they could be unique in the first 8) because it kept things simple when changing a function scope variable into a global scope variable.

At least that's what *I* did back then.

Comment: C90 had a minimum length of 6 characters, monocase, for external identifiers (e.g. function names).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm doing this from memory for compilers I [personally] used from 1981-1989 that were on Unix v7, System III, and System V. I can't recall if Solaris (nee SunOS) or Microport Unix were any better. I used my first Linux system in 1993 but I can't recall if the early versions still had the restriction or not. I _think_ linux (using `gcc`) had things lifted by then.

Comment: I'm working from memory too — starting 1983 for C.  "The Annotated C Standard" by H Schildt is 50% standard text and 50% nonsense contributed by the author.  However, it is mostly good when quoting the standard, and section 5.2.4.1 _Translation limits_ lists two immediately relevant ones: • _31 significant initial characters in an internal identifier or macro name. • 6 significant initial characters in an external identifier._  I seem to remember reading somewhere that the C90 standard authors struggled with the 6 character limit, but there were (mainframe) systems where that was unavoidable.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The compilers I was using [up to 1986] were derived/ported from the original Unix v7 compiler. They weren't standard conforming [AFAIK] because the code predated it. I know that 8 chars for the linker was the limit. I don't know about uppercase->lowercase because I _always_ used lowercase for all symbols. I was looking for longer names, so I _tested_ an 8 char C global and verified the 7 char limit in the linker. I don't know of any Unix port to a mainframe (e.g. IBM S/370) in that timeframe. So, a C compiler would be using the native OS/VS1 or VM/370/CMS linker

Comment: Fortunately, it isn't a current problem.  The first version of Unix I used was derived from 7th Edition Unix (with some System III extensions, at least later in the life cycle), and AFAICR it had the 8-character limit you remember.  I worked on a project where the 6-character rule was enforced because of the systems used by collaborators — this was years before C89/C90 was published.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Just curious. Was the SysIII system ported by Unisoft? They did a lot of SysIII/SysV ports to mc68000 systems for startups that manufactured them (I worked for one). At the time, Sun ported BSD (from the VAX port?). And, Altos [Computer Systems] ported Unix v7 to 8086 and mc68000 multiuser systems.

Comment: I was introduced to Unix on the [ICL Perq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PERQ) (aka Three Rivers Corporation Perq). The first ones used a 16-bit microprogrammed chip (one side effect of which was that the `char *` address for a given memory location was numerically different from the `anything_bigger *` address of the same location — you didn't risk not declaring `malloc()` properly!). And casts to/from `char *` were necessary; there was no `void *` yet. The Unix o/s was called PNX (Perq uNiX, or thereabouts; also not a good abbreviation for I18N, though the ICL One-Per-Desk or OPD was worse).

Comment: *The C Programming Language* (1978) says (in Appendix A): "An identifier is a sequence of letters and digits... No more than the first eight characters are significant... External identifiers, which are used by various assemblers and loaders, are more restricted: DEC PDP-11, 7 characters, 2 cases; Honeywell 6000, 6 characters, 1 case; IBM 360/370, 7 characters, 1 case; Interdata 8/32, 8 characters, 2 cases." (My first exposure was on a PDP-11; on the IBM 360, I mostly used Fortran (WATFOR) but sometimes SNOBOL, which was really cool.) Anyway, that's where 6 characters, one case comes from.

Comment: I just checked the future directions in §6.9.1 in the C90 standard, and it says _6.9.1 External names — Restriction of the significance of an external name to fewer than 31 characters or to only one case is an obsolescent feature that is a concession to existing implementations._

Answer (score 2):

I'm quoting my teacher here. He said that, back in the day, monitors were way smaller so if you use long names, your code won't fit on your screen anymore. C is an old language (the '70s) so it's basically a bunch of legacy we have to deal with now. Changing it would break to much existing code (Linux/unix is written in C for example).

Also the people using it are sometimes from that time so they are used to this style.

Comment: *C is an old language (the '90s)*  make that a bit older: the **'70s**

Comment: Changed. Thanks

Comment: *Also the people using it are sometimes from that time so they are used to this style.* :)