# What does "f" stand for in C standard library function names?

Tags: c, naming, libc

What does `f` stand for in the name of C standard library functions? I have noticed that a lot of functions have an `f` in their name, and this does not really make sense to me.

For example: `fgets`, `fopen`, `printf`, `scanf`, `sqrtf` and so on.

Comment: the leading `f` and the trailing `f` both have a meaning, but are unrelated.

Comment: First two: "file". Second two: "format" or "formatted". `fscanf()` and `fprintf()`: both.

Comment: if it's a prefix, then it's generally "file". e.g. `(f)ile (open)`. If the F is postfix, then usually it's 'format'. `(print) (f)ormat`. `(f)ile (print) (f)ormat`

Comment: Another use of 'f' is for `float` as in `ceilf()`, `round()`, ... In `math.h` functions there are also suffixes to indicate the return type.

Comment: Shorthands like these, and the similar `s` in `sprintf`, `sscanf`, and the `str` prefixes were preferred over full names because initially [only 6 were significant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290165/whats-the-exact-role-of-significant-characters-in-c-variables).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Your question in general is too general but I can explain a few examples.

- [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), [`fopen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen), [`fclose`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fclose), … — The ”f“ stands for “file”.  These functions accept or return a `FILE *` pointer as opposed to a file number as the POSIX functions do.
- [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), … — The ”f“ stands for “formatted”.  These functions accept a format string.
- [`fprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), [`fscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) — This is a combination of the above two.
- [`sinf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/sin), [`cosf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/cos), … — The “f” stands for `float` (to distinguish from the `double` alternatives).  Note that this fits quite nicely with suffixing floating point literals with an `f` as in `1.5f`.
- Finally, as Deduplicator [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27949512/what-does-f-stand-for-in-c-standard-library-function-names#comment44294292_27949622), there are some names such as [`free`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free), [`floor`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/floor) or [`setbuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setbuf) (“set buffer”) where the “f” simply appears as a natural language character.

The tradition of pre- or suffixing names with single letters that indicate the type of the arguments is a necessity in C that has become obsolete in C++ thanks to overloading.  Actually, overloading in C++ works by the compiler automatically adding those suffixes again under the hood to the generated symbols by a process called [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

Comment: And sometimes it's just a leading f, like in `free`, or a trailing one like in `sizeof`.

Comment: I think @Deduplicator 's comment should be another bullet on the answer

Comment: @Deduplicator I think in the case of `free` and `sizeof` the f is just part of a word :)

Answer (score 8):

The leading f refers to the type that function operates on:

- `fgets`: use `gets` on a `FILE *` handle instead of just `stdin`
- `fopen`: open a file, and return it as a `FILE *` (instead of a file descriptor which the original `open` does)

The trailing f means that it uses a formatting string:

- `printf`: print out according to the format specifier
- `scanf`: read in according to the format

And combined, you get things like:

- `fprintf`: print out to a particular `FILE *` according to the format specifier

When you consider things like the `math.h` functions, then the trailing f designates that the particular function operates on operands of type `float` like so:

- `powf`: take the exponent of `float`s
- `powl`: take the exponent of `long double`s

Comment: how about fabsf? there is 2 f's in that and file doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 6):

A leading `f` stands for `file`, a trailing one stands for `formatted`; 
for example, `sscanf` is used to scan `s`trings for values in a pattern as specified by a format, whilst `fprintf` prints formatted text to a file.

EDIT: Oh, and then there's math functions from `math.h` that will have type suffixes like `atanf` for calculating the arcustangens for float values.

Comment: Don't forget `math.h` functions eh :-)

Answer (score 4):

I am under the impression that for `fgets` and `fopen` the `f` stands for file.

For `printf` and `scanf` I believe that the `f` stands for formatted. This is at least partially supported by the [Wikipedia article on scanf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string).

Answer (score 1):

In functions from the `stdio` library, the preceeding `f` in things like `fread`, `fprintf`, `fwrite`, etc.  stands for 'file'.  The `f` at the end of functions like `printf` and `scanf` stands for 'format'.  Thus printf is FORMATTED printing, meaning that you can use things liek `%d` and `%s` in it.

In math functions a suffix of `f` usually means `float`.