# What does the letter ‘f’ stand for in printf(), scanf() and ‘g’ in seekg()

Tags: c++, c

I can't find the full name (expanded meaningful name) of the functions `printf()`, `scanf()`, `seekg()`.

These guys seem to be like below ▼

printf

- print format
- print format string
- print function

scanf

- scan format
- scan format string
- scan function

seekg

- seekGlobalFileStreamCursor (What the..?)

Can you say where the names come from, or what they mean?

Comment: What do you mean by "full name"?

Comment: What is the full name of `x` in a statement like `int x = 0;`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27949512/what-does-f-stand-for-in-c-standard-library-function-names

Comment: @M.M this question was reopened after the English was cleaned up enough to make the question comprehensible.

Answer (score 8):

`printf` is an abbreviation for "print formatted"

`scanf` is an abbreviation for "scan formatted"

`seekg` is an abbreviation for "seek the *get* (read) *pointer*"... as opposed to `seekp`, which manages the *put* (write) *pointer*.