# stdio.h why BUFSIZ instead of BUFSIZE

Tags: c, libc

I wonder does anyone have an idea why the name `BUFSIZ` used for Default buffer size in `stdio.h` header file is not `BUFSIZE`? Is there any meaning in not using the last letter E?

```c
/* Default buffer size.  */
#define BUFSIZ 8192
```

Comment: `Is there any meaning in not using the last letter E?` Its shorter. There is no other reason.

Comment: Other than [that's what the C standard says](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.1p3): "`BUFSIZ` which expands to an integer constant expression that is the size of the buffer used by the setbuf function"?

Comment: Unix and C get criticized for weird, often inconsistent, idiosyncratic naming. Thompson himself (chief author of Unix) has said if there's one thing he'd change about Unix, it's the spelling of `creat` where he'd add the final `e`. It's similar with `BUFSIZ`, I guess.

Comment: Also early compilers used to only work with very short names. That's where the tendency to shorten probably mostly originated from.

Comment: Don't look for things that make sense and were skilfully designed in stdio.h. It is perhaps the worst software library ever designed, all categories, all languages.

Comment: @PetrSkocik I suspect something like that.  Per [C89 translation limits](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#2.2.4.1): "6 significant initial characters in an external identifier".  Of course, that's right after "31 significant initial characters in an internal identifier or a macro name", which would apply to the `BUFSIZ` macro, so I'd think it's only a hint as to what the actual answer is.

Comment: Bytes used to be very expensive.

Comment: You could switch to Java, where names less than 40 characters are considered insufficiently enterprisy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38042724/17034

Comment: Why would you expect `BUFSIZE` instead of `BUFFER_SIZE`?

Comment: To add to the above, programmers also enjoy typing less.

Comment: @Horok, Think of memory costing [$0.30/byte](https://aiimpacts.org/trends-in-dram-price-per-gigabyte/) (not giga, mega, kilo) in 1972 when C originated when minimum wage was $1.60.

Comment: Thanks for all valuable answers and opinions. That helps me to understand a lot